# IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am new to Django Rest Framework I get an integrity error which I am trying to resolve

**Intro:** I have 2 models `Patient` and `Embryo`. Patient is a ForeignKey to Django's default User. There is only 1 user who is a SuperUser. All Patients belong to SuperUser. Each Patient can have many embryo's. I am creating the views for the 2 models using Django Rest Framework's  `ModelViewset`

> IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

Below is the screenshot of the error message that I am getting

[image]

**Below are my models**

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    """Patients model which has all the patients information"""
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


class Embryo(models.Model):
    """A ForeignKey model to the patient"""
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    karyotype = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    down_syndrome = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ("M", "Male"),
        ("F", "Female"),

    )
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code_name
```

I a using `ModelViewSet` to create instances for my models **below are my views.**

```
 class PatientsApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles Creating, reading and updating Patients"""

    serializer_class = serializers.PatientsSerializer
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    search_fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "phone", "email",)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)


class EmbroApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles Creating, reading and updating Patients"""

    serializer_class = serializers.EmbryoSerializer
    queryset = Embryo.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    search_fields = ("code_name", "karyotype", "sex", "down_syndrome",)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(patient__id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

**Below is my serializers.py**

```
class PatientsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for the patients model."""

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ("id", "first_name", "last_name", "phone", "email")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """Create and return a new patient"""

        patient = Patient(
            first_name=validated_data["first_name"],
            last_name=validated_data["last_name"],
            phone=validated_data["phone"],
            email=validated_data["email"]
        )
        patient.save()
        return patient


class EmbryoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Embryo
        fields = ("id", "patient", "code_name", "karyotype", "down_syndrome", "sex")

        def create(self, validated_data):
            """Create and return a new embryo"""

            embryo = Embryo(
                code_name=validated_data["code_name"],
                karyotype=validated_data["karyotype"],
                down_syndrome=validated_data["down_syndrome"],
                sex=validated_data["sex"]
            )
            embryo.save()
            return embryo
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

**Below is the Traceback as requested by @Håken Lid**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/patient/

Django Version: 2.1.2
Python Version: 3.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'patients']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, Samir, Tendulkar, 2012795973, 2018-11-04 13:17:02.923723+00, 2018-11-04 13:17:02.923802+00, samnik_12345@hotmail.com, null).
) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py" in view
  116.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in create
  21.         self.perform_create(serializer)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/genomic_prediction/src/genomic_project/patients/views.py" in perform_create
  51.         serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save
  214.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/genomic_prediction/src/genomic_project/patients/serializers.py" in create
  21.         patient.save()

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  718.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  748.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  831.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  869.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1136.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1289.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "/home/samir/PycharmProjects/GenomeVenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /patient/
Exception Value: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, Samir, Tendulkar, 2012795973, 2018-11-04 13:17:02.923723+00, 2018-11-04 13:17:02.923802+00, samnik_12345@hotmail.com, null).
```

I added user to the serializer see image below and removed the below code but the error is still the same

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

[image]

```
Views
```

[image]

Comment: Include the actual traceback text instead of a screenshot. Notice the "switch to copy-and-paste view" link in the error page? Click that link to get the raw traceback. That's what you should include when asking questions. (Also read the traceback yourself. Understanding the traceback is essential when fixing bugs)

Comment: Can you include the `PatientsSerializer` class ?

Comment: @HåkenLid I have included my serializes and Trackback as per your request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `PatientsSerializer.create` method throws away the `user` field from your serializer input data.

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    """Create and return a new patient"""

    patient = Patient(
        first_name=validated_data["first_name"],
        last_name=validated_data["last_name"],
        phone=validated_data["phone"],
        email=validated_data["email"]
        # you need a `user` as well.
    )
    patient.save()
    return patient
```

It's unclear why you have a custom create method at all. Have you tried simply removing it from the serializer? The default `ModelSerializer.create` method uses the entire `validated_data` dictionary. Just add `user` to the `PatientsSerializer.Meta.fields`

```
class PatientsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for the patients model."""

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ("id", "user", "first_name", "last_name", "phone", "email")
```

Comment: I added user to the serializer see image above in the question and removed the below code but the error is still the same `    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)`

Comment: You must also remove the `create` method from the serializer.

Comment: I did see image above however the error is still the same

Comment: No. You must keep the `perform_create` in the viewset class and remove the `create` from the serializer class.