# null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint in post request , serialzier

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

This is my views and serializer ,
when I post some data , getting null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
after passing user_id also same issue

views

```
serializer_class = subSerializer()

class subView():
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
```

serializer.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
         ....................

class subSerialzier(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
       class Meta:
    model = RecipeSubmission
    fields = (
        'id',
        'user',
        'name',
         .......)
```

Comment: Can you share the POST payload that you use? Apart of that this code is a bit messy (i.e. the indentations are off) - please use a formatter of your choice, preferably [black](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Can you include only the important parts and all the important parts? How does the `RecipeSubmission` model look like? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53142827/3623609) is an example of well-asked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to get the user object and add it to the data before creation.
Right now you must be only giving an integer for the 'user' field.. which should be an user object.

```
class subView(request):
    new_data = request.data
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.data['user']) # that is if you are sending the use Id from the frontend
    new_data['user']=user
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=new_data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
```

Try this and see